# How do i draw the following triangles using 2-d arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Using a 50 by 70, 2-Dimensional array, write a java program that draws the figure below.?It doesn't have to be exact but it must at least look like that

```
                                 *      *
                               ****    ****
                              ******  ******
                     ************************
                      ******  ******      
                       ****    ****
                         *       *
```

I tried the following code but no luck

```
import java.util.*;

public class triangle
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
  int height = 70;
   int x = 1, y = 70;

    int j;

  char triangularArray[][] = new char[50][70];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(j=-i; j<=i; j++){
          triangularArray[x+i][y+j]='*';
        }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<triangularArray.length; i++) {
        for( j=0; j<triangularArray.length; j++) {
           System.out.println(triangularArray[i][j]==0 ? ' ' : '*');
        }
       System.out.println("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be your homework. Please try atleast and show some of your efforts if you're in problem.

Comment: Homework. As for the answer posted, I dont't think you need array with values but you need the logic to print the above structure (based on my exp as I also have printed such structures in school)

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I am not familiar with 2-d arrays and so its difficult for me to display the above structure. I am able to do it without the 2-d array

Comment: I tried using this code but no luck
import java.util.*;

public class triangle
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
  int height = 70;
   int x = 1, y = 70;

    int j;
 
  char triangularArray[][] = new char[50][70];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(j=-i; j<=i; j++){
          triangularArray[x+i][y+j]='*';
        }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<triangularArray.length; i++) {
        for( j=0; j<triangularArray.length; j++) {
           System.out.println(triangularArray[i][j]==0 ? ' ' : '*');
        }
       System.out.println("\n");
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Make a 50 by 70 array. Where you want a star to show up put a 1 in the array(since the array is your figure). Then when you print the array if it's 0 print just a space, when it's 1 print a * .

Comment: I tried using this code but still no luck.
import java.util.*;

public class triangle
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
  int height = 70;
   int x = 1, y = 70;

    int j;
 
  char triangularArray[][] = new char[50][70];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    for(j=-i; j<=i; j++){
          triangularArray[x+i][y+j]='*';
        }
  }
  for(int i=0; i<triangularArray.length; i++) {
        for( j=0; j<triangularArray.length; j++) {
           System.out.println(triangularArray[i][j]==0 ? ' ' : '*');
        }
       System.out.println("\n");
    }
  }
}